# Can you use ARRAYFORMULA to SUM multiple columns changing dynamically

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

*edit: must work with blank rows*

I have a list of users in Column F and in Row 1 a list of dates.
I want to use ARRAYFORMULA to sum the values from relevant columns per each user. As an example, this sums 4 columns (F,G,H,I) per user:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F1:F),G1:G+H1:H+I1:I+J1:J,""))

My question is, if it possible to sum for a dynamic number of columns. For example, I'll choose a number (e.g 7, 30...) and it will sum the relevant number of columns.
Can this be done?

Here's a spreadsheet with the above data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17hyBEF1va4GMYZUFkDxxjJ0pXH2oCccgIaBT79GIsGc/edit#gid=0

In A2 I choose how many columns, and it will sum the relevant number of columns. In C1 I use such a formula to sum 4 columns using ARRAYFORMULA as an example (which is static, not dynamic).

Note that there was a nice solution, but because there is a blank row (#3) it causes the suggested solution to leave the sum for the final row (#7) empty. I'm looking for a solution that will work with blank rows.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 parameters:

- `A2`: no of cols
- `G2`: top left cell of values
- `F:F`: col of row field (to count number of rows)

```
=ArrayFormula(MMULT(N(INDIRECT(CELL("address",G2)&":"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(F:F),COLUMN(G2)+A2-1,4))),N(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(INDIRECT(CELL("address",G2)&":"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(F:F),COLUMN(G2)+A2-1,4)))^0))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Can you please explain the login of the formula?

Comment: One more thing, if I add a blank row the formula doesn't apply to the last row. Is this something that can be solved? I added row 3 (blank), so now it doesn't apply for row 7